# How to add devices specific images in app using storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I am developing an app using xocode 6 & iOS 8.I am trying to add an image on app.Default size of the image is 57*57 when i add this image it looks too big on iPhone 4 where as it looks nice on iPhone 6 & 6plus i want to know is it possible to add different screen size images for different phones through storyboards with out using any code.I have tried using images.xcassets but that does not provide any option to add images for different iPhones.Please guide me.I am just fresher in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: who the hell is voting it down.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Use these values and adjust the size of your image according to them.

Comment: the example you have given of appcode is only for the single iPhone where as in mycase i want my image to be fit on all iOS devices.

Comment: Well then you need to wright some code and define the version. And adjust the image size programmatically, depending on screensize.

Comment: I was expecting this answer as for defining height & width of any view.I need to write down some code in order to support the all devices.Where as so many tutorials are saying we don't need to write down any code if we are working with xcode 6 & iOS 8.

Comment: I don't want to write the code.I just want to do with the help of story boards.

Comment: All does amazing tutorials promising you that you can build an app without using any code are sometimes to good to be true. What you want to do is not possible using only Stroyboard. The bad news is that you need to code, but the good news is that what you want to do, is not that complicated.

Comment: Thats's really bad.I need to code for resizing images for different screen sizes.Is this the similar case for the view as well because i have some views as well.